# How to change the javadoc @-clauses order of IntelliJ IDEA code formatter?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, code-formatting

IntelliJ IDEA code formatter will auto reformat the order of javadoc @-clauses like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @param 
 * @author 
 * @since
 */
```

But I want the following order when reformat：

```
/**
 *
 * @author 
 * @param 
 * @since
 */
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to configure different order. Please vote for this request: [IDEA-204650](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-204650).